# Mail.Send permission status blank

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-app-registration

I'm attempting to send mail from my app as the current user. When I add in the Delegated Mail.Send API Permission to do this, the status is empty - it is neither 'granted' or 'not granted'; neither is it showing an error. I also tried adding Mail.ReadWrite which didn't work either. I left it a few days to see if it was just being slow to update.

These permissions do not require Admin - it says 'No' in the Admin Consent Required column.  I've successfully added other permission types in the past as you can see.
[image: API Permissions for App Registration]
How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: The status will be updated as `granted` only when **admin** grants consent. It won't change just by adding permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By ***default***, Status will be `blank` when you add permissions for
> which *Admin consent required* is **No**.
>
> If *Admin consent required* is **Yes**, Status will be `Not granted for Tenantname`

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added few **API permissions** like this:

[image]

When **admin** granted consent, Status changed to `Granted for Tenantname` like below:

[image]

Now when I added `Mail.ReadWrite` and `Mail.Send` permissions, Status is **blank** like below:

[image]

To change `status` of those permissions, grant **admin consent** as below:

[image]

When **admin consent** is granted, Status turned to `Granted for Tenantname` successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: This does seem to be the case.  The status did change when Admin granted consent. (we had a red herring initially - there were two App Registrations with the same name and the administrators were looking at the wrong one).  The permissions didn't work until admin granted consent. Why does it have 'No' in the 'Admin Consent Required' column though? Our Admin couldn't explain it either.